# How to add a class subview, in another class as a subview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have two `UIViewController` class, in first class I have a `UIScrollView` as a **subview** and I want to add this `UIScrollView` in another class as a **subview** .

Comment: there are several ways are there to achieve this,  one is u just pass that scroll view constructor to  second view controller...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you gave some code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[view1 addSubView:view2];`.if you added the `UIScrollView` on `UIViewController` add that controller view to other view on which you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work properly, once you added a `UIView` to one `UIView` I don't think it's proper to add it to another subview. You might need to explicitly call `removeFromSuperview` before adding it to another view. Ensure though that it's retained enough to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `UIScrollview` as a property of `viewController` A .i.e by assigning it `@property(nonatomic,retain)` in the .h file of class A and synthesizing it in .m file of class A..

Further in class B create a instance of class A in B .h file eg: `ViewController *VC1;` and synthesize it in B's .m file

Now..in `ViewController A` when you are calling `ViewController B` (Typically when you are pushing) 
Eg :

```
ViewControllerB *VC2 = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
VC2.VC1 = self;

[self navigationController pushViewCOntroller:VC2 animated:YES];
```

Now in Class B where you want the `scrollView` of Class A to be added ,

write the following in Class B

```
   [ self.view addSubView:VC1.scrollView];
```